# How to properly use aggregate in Django

Tags: python, django

I have the following model:

```
class InvoiceEntry(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='entries', verbose_name=_("Invoice"))
    line = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name=_("Print Line"))
    text = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Print Text"))
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name=_("Amount"))
    unit_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Unit Price"))
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True, validators=[validate_invoice_target_models])
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_separator = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want to obtain the total of a single invoice, so I get a query set using: `invoice_entries = InvoiceEntry.objects.filter(invoice_id=2227)`, and if I apply `values('amount', 'unit_price')`, I get:

```
{'amount': 0, 'unit_price': None}
{'amount': 4, 'unit_price': 11.5}
{'amount': 2, 'unit_price': 11.5}
{'amount': 2, 'unit_price': 11.5}
{'amount': 2, 'unit_price': 11.5}
{'amount': 2, 'unit_price': 11.5}
{'amount': 2, 'unit_price': 11.5}
{'amount': 1, 'unit_price': 11.5}
{'amount': 4, 'unit_price': 11.5}
{'amount': 2, 'unit_price': 11.5}
{'amount': 2, 'unit_price': 11.5}
{'amount': 2, 'unit_price': 11.5}
{'amount': 1, 'unit_price': 11.5}
{'amount': 2, 'unit_price': 11.5}
{'amount': 1, 'unit_price': 26.0}
{'amount': 2, 'unit_price': 11.5}
{'amount': 2, 'unit_price': 11.5}
{'amount': 2, 'unit_price': 11.5}
{'amount': 2, 'unit_price': 11.5}
{'amount': 2, 'unit_price': 11.5}
{'amount': 2, 'unit_price': 11.5}
{'amount': 2, 'unit_price': 11.5}
{'amount': 9, 'unit_price': 23.0}
```

That counts for a total of **716.00**, but when I try to aggregate:

```
total = InvoiceEntry.objects.filter(invoice_id=2227).aggregate(amount=Sum('amount', field=('amount * unit_price')))
```

I get:

```
{'amount': 52}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: i'm not sure what `field` kwarg does inside the `Sum` have you tried using `annotate` then `aggregate`? Something like `annotate('total'=F('amount') * F('unit_price')).aggregate(Sum('total'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do aggregation based on invoice you need to use annotate. Aggregate will work on all invoice present in the model. It is something like below without group by in sql language.

```
select sum(column1 * column2) from table;
```

Annotate is something with group by.

```
select invoice, sum(column1 * column2) from table group by invoice;
```

Below queryset will solve your problem.

```
from your_app import models
from django.db.models import F, Sum, FloatField

m = models.InvoiceEntry.objects.values('invoice').annotate(sum=Sum(F('amount') * F('unit_price'), output_field=FloatField()))

<QuerySet [{'invoice': 1, 'sum': 48.0}, {'invoice': 2, 'sum': 8.0}]>
```

This will provide all invoice's sum. if you need specific invoice, you can use filter.

```
m = models.InvoiceEntry.objects.filter(invoice=1).values('invoice').annotate(sum=Sum(F('amount')
* F('unit_price'), output_field=FloatField()))

<QuerySet [{'invoice': 1, 'sum': 48.0}]>
```

Answer (score 0):

The F objects in Django allow you to do extra calculations. The F objects generate SQL expressions that describe operations at the database level.

Try this and it should count the total properly. This assumes you are using Django 1.8+

```
from django.db.models import Sum, F
InvoiceEntry.objects.filter(invoice_id=2227).aggregate(total=Sum(F('amount') * F('unit_price'))
```

More about the F expressions in Django here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions

Comment: Please add the relevant details what your code does and why it works like this to your answer. I assume your code is correct, but it does not explain what you're doing.